# License Issue when Watson Studio Academic Trial Installed on 2nd computer

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio, spss-modeler

I successfully installed SPSS Modeller Academic Trial and Watson Studio Desktop Academic Trial on my old computer on September 9th. Then I uninstalled these two from the old computer and tried to install them on my new laptop a week later. Then I got the message saying that"Logged in somewhere else", and ask me to click "Manage" login to switch to my new computer. But there is nothing I can do when I clicked on "Manage Logins" button. I cannot log into either Watson Studio desktop or SPSS Modeller. Could anybody please help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Our team recommends doing the following:

1. Visit the following link: https://myibm.ibm.com/dashboard/
2. Click the button entitled "manage" under Watson Studio Desktop
3. Select the button entitled "manage devices"
4. Hit "deactivate"

For further guidance, follow the steps here: https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/2017/10/19/change-machines-spss-statistics-subscription/

If you have any additional questions feel free to continue the conversation here or visit our new Watson Studio and Machine Learning Community: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/watsonstudio/home